# How to make an image grow in size during an animation

Tags: ios, animation

Basically, I am trying to simulate an explosion that starts small but grows until it takes up the entire screen.

```
-(void)Dying{
    [BirdMovement invalidate];
    [TunnelMovement invalidate];
    [TunnelMovement2 invalidate];
    [TunnelMovement3 invalidate];
    [TunnelMovement4 invalidate];
    [BirdMovement_orange invalidate];
    [BirdMovement_yellow invalidate];
    [BirdMovement_green invalidate];
    [BirdMovement_blue invalidate];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    Bird.frame=CGRectMake(Bird.center.x,Bird.center.y,23,37);

    Bird.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Explode1.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Explode2.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Explode3.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Explode4.png"]

                        , nil];

    Bird.animationDuration = 3;
    Bird.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [Bird startAnimating];

    [self.window addSubview:Bird];

    [self performSelector:@selector(Dead) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];

}

-(void)Dead{

    [Bird stopAnimating];
    [self GameOver];
}
```

I tried messing with the `CGRectMake` saying things like

```
[Bird.frame=CGRectMake(Bird.center.x,Bird.center.y,23   +5  ,37   +5);]
```

But obviously this wont work cause its just making it (28, 42).

Comment: JFYI, a word about naming conventions: in Objective-C, only type names and macros start with upper-case characters. Methods and variables should start with lower-case characters.

Comment: And what is your question? You have an `UIImageView` and want to change its frame, animated?

Comment: Yea, sorry.  I have to clean up my code.

Comment: I want each .png to be bigger in size than the one before it.

Comment: via the `transform` property? or via the `layer.transform` property? working with the `frame` is extremely resource consuming way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will animate your imageView to your new size over 3 seconds.

```
UIImageView * bird = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];

bird.animationImages = @[
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"bird1"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"bird2"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"bird3"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"bird4"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"bird5"]
                         ];

[self.view addSubview:bird];

[bird startAnimating];

[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{

    bird.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);

}];
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed except I cant figure out why its not using my array of images at all when I use this?

Comment: I just ran the above code and both the images and the frame animate. Could you try this?